# Cakephp authentication: 2.4.2

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

My problem is I have a different model name for the user table: Breeder. My login page always says incorrect username or password, because the password entered is not hashed.

Here is the view:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create();
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Form->end('Log in');
    echo $this->Html->link('Register', '/breeders/register');
?>
```

Here is the AppController:

class AppController extends Controller {

```
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
public $components = array('Session', 'Paginator',
  'Auth' => array(
    'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'breeders', 'action' => 'login'),
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'breeders', 'action' => 'desk'),
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'breeders', 'action' => 'login'),
    'authorize' => array('Controller'),
    'authenticate' => array(
      'Form' => array(
        'fields' => array(
          'username' => 'login',
          'password' => 'password'),
        'passwordHasher' => array(
          'className' => 'Simple',
          'hashType' => 'sha256'
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );

public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    return true;
}

public function beforeFilter() {

    $this->Auth->allow('login', 'logout', 'register', 'profile');
}
}
```

My login method:

```
public function login() {
  $this->set('title_for_layout', __('Connection'));

  if ($this->Session->read('Auth.Breeder')) {
    return $this->redirect('/');
  }

  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
      return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    }
  }
}
```

And the beforeSave method in the model:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {

  if (!$this->id) {
    $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
    $this->data['Breeder']['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
      $this->data['Breeder']['password']
      );
  }
  return true;
}
```

I don't know what I need to add to make the password be hashed. Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't do it without manual hashing, I used this code in the Controller login function:

```
public function login() {

  $this->set('title_for_layout', __('Connection'));

  if ($this->Session->read('Auth.Breeder')) {
    return $this->redirect('/');
  }

  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
    $this->request->data['Breeder']['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
      $this->request->data['Breeder']['password']
    );
    $breeder = $this->Breeder->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Breeder.login' => $this->request->data['Breeder']['username']), 'fields' => array('id')));

    $this->request->data['Breeder'] = array_merge($this->request->data['Breeder'], array('id' => $breeder['Breeder']['id']));

    if ($this->Auth->login($this->request->data['Breeder'])) {
      return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone has a better solution, please don't hesitate to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you change User model using

> array('userModel' => 'Breeder')

Refer to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers

Comment: It seems that I have taken it off during testing several possibilities, but I had tried with it. Now I just added it, as my login function works (I hash the password manually, so it should be hashing twice) I guess it was not the solution. Thank you anyway